# ng-repeat with variabile as something

Tags: angularjs

Let's imagine I have an array I want to iterate. So standard way I would just

```
<div ng-repeat=obj in arr>
```

Which works correctly ofc. But let's also imagine situation i will work whole time just with `obj` property `data`.

So for example:

```
<span>{{obj.data.firstName}}</span>
<span>{{obj.data.lastName}}</span>
```

It works but it start looking ugly, and just in case it will have one aditional subobject or array it can go even worser.

So I hope if there is something like:

```
<div ng-repeat=obj.data as o in arr>
```

I didnt find any information about it in [Angular Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) but I belieave it could be possible or atleast work arounded.

Any idea?

**EDIT:**
e.g. array:

```
[{
    "data": {
        "Name": "MyName",
        "Gender": "female"
    },
    "data2": {
        "nothing": true
    }
}, {
    "data": {
        "Name": "MyNam2e",
        "Gender": "male"
    },
    "data2": {
        "nothing": true
    }
}]
```

Comment: Not really a good way to do it. You *could* use `ngInit` to set a variable = to `obj.data`

Comment: Let's check my question (edited), I have to iterate that main array from response but know that I dont need first object but just obj.data

Comment: You could also just expose an array of data in your controller: `$scope.dataArray = $scope.arr.map(function(obj) { return obj.data; }));`